# Max size for background image CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have a 70 by 50 px box and I have various images, (SVG files, so no size) I want to keep their aspect ratio, but some images are portrait and some are landscape sized. So I can do:

```
background-size: 70px auto;
```

and that will work for all the landscape icons. But it will stretch the portrait images and make them taller, so they will still have the correct aspect ratio but the top and bottom will be cut off.

is there some kind of background-max-size?

(alternatively, the only reason I'm using background image is because you can center align the image, horizontally **and vertically**, so the alternative is to find how to vertically align an img element within a li element.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem that CSS can't solve on its own. There are JavaScript libraries that will do this job. If you use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/), you can find a plugin or roll your own function.

Grab the [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) of the image, and calculate the ratio (x/y). If the ratio is greater than 70/50 (1.4), set the width to 70px and the height to (70 * x/y). If the ratio is less than 70/50 (1.4), set the height to 50px and the width to (50 * x/y).

Also see [CSS vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

If you use browsers that don't support vertical-align, you can position the image absolutely at 50%, and set the top margin to (width * -0.5) using JavaScript. That will align the middle of the image with the middle of the parent element, which is the same as vertical center alignment.

Comment: Ugh, why can't CSS just do center vertical align like it does horizontal centering. CSS could be so much easier, sensible an obvious !!!

Comment: @Jonathan CSS can do vertical-align just fine, only Microsoft screwed it up as usual. Don't blame CSS, blame M$ :)

Comment: Microsoft? what they got to do with it? And if I out vertical-align:centre on the imgs parent it dos not align vertically

Comment: @Jonathan vertical-align must be "middle", not "center" (Yeah, it's inconsistent.)

Comment: @kijin, right :) I meant middle, I used middle in my code, just wrote center here.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The correct answer is below currently has 23 upvotes.

Answer (score 35):

i'm a little (10 years) late to this question so previous answers weren't good enough for me

we have a css function called **clamp** which can define size with min & max values: `clamp(<min-size>, <expected-size>, <max-size>)`

```css
width: clamp(100px, 10vw, 500px);
```

and yes my friend you can use that for `background-size` too.

```css
background-size: clamp(1000px, 80%, 1500px) auto;
```

*IE support is questionable as always.

Comment: This method wasn't available at the time the questio nwas asked, but now that it exists it definitely should be the checked answer!

Comment: This is super helpful!

Answer (score 34):

It's not that hard doing that with CSS

- 1st, please take a look at [the Mozilla Specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) for mixed units for `background-size`.
- 2nd, please consider simply setting `background-size: contain;` (IE9+, Safari 4.1+, FF 3.0+, Opera 10+) and `min/max-width/height` for the container element.

Comment: "background-size: contain;" doesn't solve the problem if a certain height is needed for the image. "min-height" for the container element will not make the image cover the height.

Comment: I have `background-size: 100%` for my use case, and then I just tell the element where I have applied the `background-image` to have a `max-size` at my largest `breakpoint`.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 25):

You can absolutely solve this problem without JavaScript using a combination of CSS3 [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) and media-queries. e.g.:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #element {
        background-size: contain;
    }
}
```

Note that neither are supported in IE8 or below, so you should include fallbacks for old IE if you still support it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is a little out of date. As [stringman5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651713/stringman5) mentions, neither of the CSS options are supported in IE8 or below. It is also not the best choice to have jQuery handle your background images if it isn't necessary. In order to use an option that includes the fallbacks for older browser, without using JavaScript, you can do something along these lines:

```
#myElement {
    background: #FFFFFF url('mybackground.jpg') no-repeat right top;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    #myElement {
        background-size: 50%;
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm using `max-width` in my media query, this means that `background-size: 50%;` will be applied UNTIL `1024px`. Beyond that point, it does it's default size. In older browsers that don't support media queries or background-size, they will ignore the options and render the maximum size of the background image (default size).

Comment: To expand on this answer, now CSS has the [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) rule to add something only if the browser supports it. It should be said though, that IE11 does not support `@supports`, so this may have unintended behaviors.